# Sending token to back end stripe objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, firebase

I can't seem to find the code to send my token to my firebase backend.

```
- (void)addCardViewController:(STPAddCardViewController *)addCardViewController didCreateToken:(STPToken *)token completion:(STPErrorBlock)completion {
    [self submitTokenToBackend:token completion:^(NSError *error) {
        if (error) {
            completion(error);
        } else {
            [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{
                [self showReceiptPage];
            }];
        }
    }];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this code,

```
STPAddress  *address = [[STPAddress alloc] init];
address.name ="Test";
address.line1 = @"Test Address-1";
address.line2 = @"Test Address-2";
address.city = @"City";
address.postalCode = @"1234";
address.state = @"State";
address.country = @"Country";



STPCard *stripCard;
stripCard = [[STPCard alloc] init];
stripCard.number = strCard_Number;
stripCard.cvc = strCard_Cvv;
stripCard.expMonth = month;
stripCard.expYear = year;
stripCard.address = address;
stripCard.currency = @"INR";


 [[STPAPIClient sharedClient] createTokenWithCard:stripCard completion:^(STPToken * _Nullable token, NSError * _Nullable error)
 {
        NSString *strMess= @"";
        if(error) {
            strMess = [error localizedDescription];    
        }
        else {
            strMess = stringValue(token.tokenId);
            strMess = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Token:\n-------\n%@\n\n\nCard Details:\n-------\n%@",strMess,token.allResponseFields];
            //[Function showAlertMessage:strMess autoHide:NO];

            NSString *strToken = @"";
            strToken = token.tokenId;

            NSLog(@"strToken: %@",strToken);
      }
      NSLog(@"strMess: %@",strMess);
 }];
```

Comment: the token is already created in my method. in the Stripe Documentation it states:  (Note: the examples in this guide assume you've written a function called submitTokenToBackend:completion: which sends your STPToken to your server). I can't seem to make this function.

Comment: every time i try the selector is not recognised or its used as a parameter

Comment: Read the official document of stripe, using this token you have called the web service as mention in stripe guidlines

Comment: Read this documents : https://stripe.com/docs/api and https://stripe.com/docs/charges